# Why is the following Nokogiri/XPath code removing tags inside the node?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, jekyll

The document going in has a structure like this:

```
<span class="footnote">Hello there, <a href="http:google.com">link</a></span>
```

The XPath search is:

```
@doc = set_nokogiri(html)

footnotes = @doc.xpath(".//span[@class = 'footnote']")
footnotes.each_with_index do |footnote, index|
    puts footnote
end
```

The above footnote becomes:

```
<span>Hello there, link</span>
```

I assume my XPath is wrong but I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

I had the wrong tag in the output and should have been more careful. The point being that the `<a>` tag is getting stripped but its contents are still included.

I also added the `set_nokogiri` line in case that's relevant.

Comment: This code does certainly not return a `p` element. Please post a sample input and code that allows to reproduce the output you show: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, getting the following result: `<span class="footnote">Hello there, <a href="http:google.com">link</a></span>`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate the problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<span class="footnote">Hello there, <a href="http:google.com">link</a></span>
EOT

footnotes = doc.xpath(".//span[@class = 'footnote']")
footnotes.to_xml # => "<span class=\"footnote\">Hello there, <a href=\"http:google.com\">link</a></span>"
footnotes.each do |f|
  puts f
end
# >> <span class="footnote">Hello there, <a href="http:google.com">link</a></span>
```

An additional problem is that the `<a>` tag has an invalid `href` URL.

```
<a href="http:google.com">link</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="http://google.com">link</a>
```

Comment: No, an XPath expression like `.//element` does not mean searching anywhere in the document - it means searching only the `descendant-or-self::` axis of the _current context node_ - which happens to be the document node in this case. Incidentally, in this case both  `.//element` and  `//element` mean the same. Then, `//span[@class = 'footnote']` is not the same as `./span[@class = 'footnote']`. The former selects `span` elements anywhere in the document, the latter only selects them if they are immediate children of the current context node.

Comment: You are welcome - but my comment is a bit too negative. `//span[@class = 'footnote']` really is clearer than `.//span[@class = 'footnote']` - +1 for that. Do you agree that it's impossible to arrive at the results the OP describes, given the input HTML and the code?

Comment: I do not get the same results the OP claims. It's poorly written Nokogiri code, but there's nothing that should strip the `<a>` tag nor do I see the problem.